# how to dispaly multilpe pins on the arcGis map in android

Tags: android, arcgis

I am new to the android...I have been working on the arcGIS map for 2 days for displaying multiple pins on the arcGIS map..I am getting output only when i am debugging instead of running.. i have to show the popup window(callout)whren taping on the pin.Please some body help me..Thanks in advance..

Here is my code

```
if (MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getLatitude().size() > 0) {

                for (int i = 0; i < MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getLatitude()
                        .size(); i++) {
                    Log.v("TEST", "size=="
                            + MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getLatitude().size());

                    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(MyXMLHandler
                            .getResponse().getLatitude().get(i).toString());
                    double langtude = Double.parseDouble(MyXMLHandler
                            .getResponse().getLongtude().get(i).toString());

                    Log.v("TEST", "lan........" + latitude + "....lng......"
                            + langtude);

                    latlong = new Point(langtude, latitude);
                    point = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(latlong,
                            SpatialReference.create(4326),
                            mMapView.getSpatialReference());

                    gLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

                    PictureMarkerSymbol pictureMarkerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol(
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s));
                    graphic = new Graphic(point, pictureMarkerSymbol);

                    gLayer.addGraphic(graphic);

                    mMapView.addLayer(gLayer);
                    mMapView.setOnSingleTapListener(Arcgis_routeActivity.this);



                }

@Override
    public void onSingleTap(final float x, final float y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.callout_xml, null);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView1.setText(MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getName().get(0)
                .toString());

        location = new Point(x, y);
        if (callout != null) {
            callout.hide();
        } else {
            callout = mMapView.getCallout();
            callout.setStyle(R.xml.calloutstyle);

        }

        callout.setOffset(0, -15);
        callout.show(location, v);
    }``
```

Comment: The problem is solved.. I make the above method run  in the asynctask background with 2 min delay..again i freezed while adding the callouts for number of pins on the map..can anyone help..Thanks advance....sorry for my bad english..

Comment: I got the callouts handling...see the below code

Answer (score 0):

```
Iam displaying multiple pins in asynctask from the raw folder..on single tap listener comparig the tapped listener lat long values with the dropped pin lat longs..



  private class LocationsDisplaying extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {

                    /** Handling XML */
                    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                    /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
                    MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
                    xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                    InputStream is = MainActivity.this.getResources()
                            .openRawResource(R.raw.service);
                    xr.parse(new InputSource(is));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                dialog.dismiss();
                new PinDisplay().execute();

            }
        }
```

class PinDisplay extends AsyncTask {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading......");
        dialog.show();

    }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    displaying_mapUI();

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    dialog.dismiss();

}
```

}

```
 private void displaying_mapUI() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Point latlong = null;
        Point point;
        Graphic graphic;
        GraphicsLayer gLayer;

        if (MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getLatitude().size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getLatitude().size(); i++) {
                Log.v("TEST", "size=="
                        + MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getLatitude().size());

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(MyXMLHandler.getResponse()
                        .getLatitude().get(i).toString());
                double langtude = Double.parseDouble(MyXMLHandler.getResponse()
                        .getLongtude().get(i).toString());

                Log.v("TEST", "lan........" + latitude + "....lng......"
                        + langtude);

                latlong = new Point(langtude, latitude);

                point = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(latlong,
                        SpatialReference.create(4326),
                        mMapView.getSpatialReference());

                gLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

                PictureMarkerSymbol pictureMarkerSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol(
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin2));

                graphic = new Graphic(point, pictureMarkerSymbol);

                gLayer.addGraphic(graphic);

                mMapView.addLayer(gLayer);

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onSingleTap(final float x, final float y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mMapView.setRotationAngle(0);
        compass.setRotationAngle(mMapView.getRotationAngle());
        compass.postInvalidate();

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.callout_xml, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // View view = createView();
        Point p = mMapView.toMapPoint(x, y);

        // Log.v("TEST", "X=" + p.getX());
        // Log.v("TEST", "Y=" + p.getY());

        SpatialReference sp = SpatialReference.create(4326);
        Point aux = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(p,
                mMapView.getSpatialReference(), sp);

        location = new Point(aux.getX(), aux.getY());

        StringTokenizer tokenst1 = new StringTokenizer(String.valueOf(aux
                .getY()), ".");
        String firstt1 = tokenst1.nextToken();

        float tapLat = Float.parseFloat(firstt1);

        StringTokenizer tokenst2 = new StringTokenizer(String.valueOf(aux
                .getX()), ".");
        String firstt2 = tokenst2.nextToken();

        float tapLng = Float.parseFloat(firstt2);

        StringTokenizer tokensl1 = new StringTokenizer(String.valueOf(latlong
                .getY()), ".");
        String firstl1 = tokensl1.nextToken();

        float staticLat = Float.parseFloat(firstl1);

        StringTokenizer tokensl2 = new StringTokenizer(String.valueOf(latlong
                .getX()), ".");
        String firstl2 = tokensl2.nextToken();

        float staticLng = Float.parseFloat(firstl2);

        Log.v("TEST", "tapLat" + tapLat);
        Log.v("TEST", "tapLng" + tapLng);

        Log.v("TEST", "staticLat" + staticLat);
        Log.v("TEST", "staticLng" + staticLng);

        if (tapLat == staticLat && tapLng == staticLng) {

            locationName = "Alberta";

        } else {

            for (int j = 0; j < MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getLatitude().size(); j++) {

                double double_lat = MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getLatitude().get(j);

                double double_long = MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getLongtude().get(j);

                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(String.valueOf(double_lat),
                        ".");
                String first = tokens.nextToken();

                Log.v("TEST", "first......" + first);

                StringTokenizer tokens1 = new StringTokenizer(
                        String.valueOf(double_long), ".");
                String first1 = tokens1.nextToken();

                Log.v("TEST", "first1111111......" + first1);

                float service_location_lat = Float.parseFloat(first);

                float service_location_lng = Float.parseFloat(first1);

                if (tapLat == service_location_lat
                        && tapLng == service_location_lng) {

                    Log.v("TEST", "if service_location_lng....."
                            + service_location_lng);
                    Log.v("TEST", "if service_location_lat........"
                            + service_location_lat);

                    locationName = MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getName().get(j)
                            .toString().trim();

                    Log.v("TESt", "locationName....." + locationName);

                    j = MyXMLHandler.getResponse().getLatitude().size();

                } else {

                    locationName = "No Results Found";
                }
            }
        }

        text.setText(locationName);

        callout.show(p, view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (locationName.equalsIgnoreCase("No Results Found")
                        || locationName.equalsIgnoreCase("Alberta")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please select Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            RouteDisplying.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Hi @gaddam nagaraju  i have a problem with callout in argis map can you please help me...

Comment: Hi Durga,tell me your issue clearly..Actually I have done this long  back..So I will help you if I can.

Comment: i have number of addresses in my database,i want to show related address in Callout when i click on symbol in map.

Comment: if possible please give me your email id ,i will explain clearly

Comment: yeah sure...This is my ID :withunag@gmail.com

Comment: did u understand my problem?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i found that may help [calloutPopupWindow](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/CalloutPopupWindow.html). sadly i havent used it but in the API it mentions it is similar to callout with the added benefit of being able to have multiple callouts.
hope this helps!